# Loop javascript in an php foreach result

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, loops

I want to have a feedback in each star of rating when I click on the star in

[image: this image]

Here is my code for now:

When I click the first row it display the title of that star. Now the second row when I click it, it does not show the title of that star..

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Feedback</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php foreach($designation_show->result() as $r){?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <inut type = "hidden" name = "template_id" id = "template" value=<?php echo $r->t_id;?> />
            <?php echo $r->question_description;?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <fieldset id='rate1' class="rating">
                <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
                <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Outstanding - 5 stars"></label>
                <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
                <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Exceeds Expectation - 4 stars"></label>
                <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
                <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meets Expectation - 3 stars"></label>
                <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
                <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Improvement Needed - 2 stars"></label>
                <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
                <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Failed - 1 star"></label> 
            </fieldset>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id='feedback'></div>
        </td>             
    </tr>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#rate1 .stars").click(function () {

                var label = $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");

                    $("#feedback").text(label.attr('title'));
                    $(this).attr("checked"); 

            });

       });
    </script>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: i want to display the title of star under it's label when i click it.

Comment: But what is happening! What is not happening! What is your actual problem

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: When i click the first row it display the title of that star. Now the second row when i click it, it does not show the title of that star..

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change the IDs to be unique
2. Do NOT loop the script

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".rating .stars").on("click",function() {
    var title = $(this).next().prop("title");
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".feedback").text(title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Feedback</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!--  loop this -->

  <!-- iteration #1 -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="template_id" id="rating1" value="..." />
      description 1
    </td>
    <td>
      <fieldset class="rating">
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="5" />
        <label class="full" for="star5" title="Outstanding - 5 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="4" />
        <label class="full" for="star4" title="Exceeds Expectation - 4 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="3" />
        <label class="full" for="star3" title="Meets Expectation - 3 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="2" />
        <label class="full" for="star2" title="Improvement Needed - 2 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="1" />
        <label class="full" for="star1" title="Failed - 1 star"></label>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td class='feedback'></td>
  </tr>

  <!-- iteration #2 -->

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="template_id" id="rating2" value="..." />
      description 2
    </td>
    <td>
      <fieldset class="rating">
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="5" />
        <label class="full" for="star5" title="Outstanding - 5 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="4" />
        <label class="full" for="star4" title="Exceeds Expectation - 4 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="3" />
        <label class="full" for="star3" title="Meets Expectation - 3 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="2" />
        <label class="full" for="star2" title="Improvement Needed - 2 stars"></label>
        <input class="stars" type="radio"  name="rating" value="1" />
        <label class="full" for="star1" title="Failed - 1 star"></label>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
    <td class='feedback'></td>
  </tr>

  <!-- end PHP loop  -->

</table>
```

Comment: There were some typos. Try again